Vue modal won't show but load perfectly fine in the web page
I'm trying to create a modal with Vue to display some information of a post so i created a component Modal.vue and loaded into the page that list all the posts, and when you click on a post you should be able to see the modal with all the information. I pass the information to the modal component with the slot tag.
The problem is that while the modal and all the html passed to the slot tag with all the information are loaded in the html DOM you can't see the modal.
I add the code of the component that uses the modal:
<template>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Todo Page</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12" style="position: relative; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" id="todoContainer" v-if="isTodoLoaded">
        <div v-for="(todo,i) in Todos" @click="showTodo(i)" class="row" id="todoDiv" style="cursor: pointer; z-index: 1; position: relative;">
            <Modal v-if="showModal[i]">
                <h5 id="todoTitle">{{ todo.heading }}</h5>
                <div class="container" id="tasksDiv">
                    <div v-for="task in todo.tasks">
                        {{ task }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <small class="text-muted" id="by-where-when">
                        Written by {{ todo.user }} in {{ todo.place }} on {{ new Date(todo.date).toDateString() }}
                    </small>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <small class="text-muted" id="tags">
                        Tags: {{ todo.tags.map(tag => "#" + tag).join(' - ') }}
                    </small>
                </p>
                <button id="closeModal" @click="closeTodo(i)">
                    Close
                </button>
            </Modal>
            {{ todo.heading }}
            <div style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; right: 0%; width: 40px;">
                <button class="btn-close" aria-label="Delete"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import axios from "axios";
    import {computed,ref,nextTick,onMounted} from "vue";
    import Modal from './Modal.vue';

    const api_url = "http://localhost:3000/";

    var Todos = ref([]);
    var showModal = ref([])
    const isTodoLoaded = computed(() => Todos.value.length > 0);

    async function getTodos(){
        try{
            const r = await axios.post(`${api_url}getTodos/-1`);
            Todos.value = r.data;
            showModal.value = Todos.value.map(() => false);
            await nextTick();
        }catch(error){
            console.log("Error: ",error);
        }
    }

    function showTodo(i){
        showModal.value[i] = true;
    }

    function closeTodo(i){
        showModal.value[i] = false;
    }

    onMounted(async () => {
        await getTodos();
    })
</script>

and the code of the modal:
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="modal">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.modal{
    background-color: black;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
</style>

I also add an image to show what the web page show:
here i was hovering the wrapper of the modal an you can see it in the web page
but when i'm hovering the div of the content of the modal it's not visible in the web page although the html content is loaded
I have tried changing the z-index value and the position but it still not working
